# How to center a SDL window in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

I was trying to find a way to create a SDL window centered on the screen and I found this code

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <SDL_syswm.h>
SDL_SysWMinfo i;
SDL_VERSION( &i.version );
if ( SDL_GetWMInfo ( &i) ) {
HWND hwnd = i.window;
SetWindowPos( hwnd, HWND_TOP, x, y, width, height, flags );
}
#endif // WIN32
```

But it's for Windows only. How can I do this in Linux?

Comment: why do you want to do it? if you want user to have window, let him to position the window anywhere.

Comment: It's nice to have the window on the center of the screen. Also, when I make a splash-screen kind of thing it wouldn't be good to have the splash at a random position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`putenv()`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_envvars) before initializing SDL and creating a window:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_getenv.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    putenv("SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED=1"); 
    // init SDL, create window, main loop, etc.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlenvvars.html

> SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED
>
> If set, tries to center the SDL window when running in X11 windowed
>   mode, or using the CyberGrafix driver.

may help you

Comment: Thanks, but I get SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED not declared error. Do I have to include something extra?